# What do we call the process of creating all of the possible morphological extractions of a given word?

Tags: computational-linguistics, morphology, lemmas

In NLP, we have two directions. One is NLU ([natural language understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_understanding)) which deals with a given text to analyze it, like:

- language detection
- normalization and text cleaning
- tokenization and segmentation
- Morphological analysis
- Stemming
- Part of speech tagging
- ...

And we have another direction called NLG ([natural language generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_generation)).

I'm developing an application in which I need to find all of the possible morphological extractions of a given word. For example in English, if I give **eat** as an input, I'm interested to get *eat*, *ate*, *eaten*, *eating*, *eats* and every other possible word that can be formed with the word **eat** as the result.

Is this a known process? Do we have a name for it? And do we have algorithms or tools that can help us in this regard?

In fact what I'm looking for is the reverse process of finding lemma of a given word and create all words that can made with a given lemma.